# Build fails when changing the deployment target from 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

My app is ARC enabled with storyboarding and set to deployment target 5.1. If I change it to 4.2 deployment target so it will work on all devices I get the following errors:

[image]

I'm not sure what to do to fix this. thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The __weak directive is not available to iOS prior to 5.0. For < 5.0 versions you need to use __unsafe_unretained directive instead of __weak

Comment: Don't forget about storyboards which are also only available on 5.0+! They aren't easily changeable though.

Comment: thanks. what would you suggest if you wanted to use storyboards but also support <5.0 versions?

Comment: You'll have to go back to good ol' UINavigationCotnroller and UIViewController hierarchy for versions prior to 5.0 in any case. So you could leave the storyboards for iOS 5.0 and later and create additional controllers for versions prior to 5.0. You generally want to use Storyboards Only in cases when you want to support 5.0 > versions and drop out the rest. So you took a really wrong approach here I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have a weak property. You should use a `unsafe_unretained` instead of `weak`. [You can find more here!](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)